# Understanding Select operation | Azure Cosmos DB Table API

Tags: c#, azure, linq, azure-cosmosdb

```
IList<string> columns = new List<string> { "PartitionKey", "GroupId" };

TableQuery<Entity> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<Entity>()
    .Select(columns)
    .Where(
        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("GroupId", QueryComparisons.GreaterThan, "5555"),
            TableOperators.And,
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThan, "4")
        )
    )
    .OrderBy("PartitionKey")
    .Take(10);
    
foreach (Entity e in table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery))
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.PartitionKey + " " + e.RowKey + " " + e.GroupId);
}
```

The table has 3 columns - PartitionKey, RowKey and GroupId. I am trying to project PartitionKey and GroupId columns.

Expected Behavior: `Console.WriteLine` should print right values for `columns` and some default value for `e.RowKey` or may be some error.

Observed Behavior: `e.RowKey` values are being printed as stored in the Table.

In the chain, I tried various places for `Select` and that didn't make a difference. What understanding am I missing? Anything to do with lazy/deferred execution?

Comment: I believe `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` would come as default even you have not added in the select column options. You can validate by removing the partition key too then the result should have partition key too.

Comment: @user1672994: You are right. I tried out select without `groupid` and only partitionkey and rowkey were returned. And by default the two are always being returned. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Sure thanks :). Posted as answer.

Comment: Would be great if you can also post some reference to a doc that mentions such behavior.

Comment: Sure, let me find the links and update the links in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the 3 system properties `partitionkey` , `rowkey` and `timestamp` will be returned.

If you don't want to fetch them, you should specify `ProjectSystemProperties=false` in the `ExecuteQuery` method(**Note**: the columns specify in the `IList<string> columns = new List<string> { "PartitionKey", "GroupId" }` still can be returned).

Here is an example, you can modify it to meet your requirement:

```
        IList<string> columns = new List<string> { "PartitionKey", "PhoneNumber" };

        TableQuery<CustomerEntity> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>()
            .Select(columns)
            .Where(
                TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PhoneNumber", QueryComparisons.Equal, "9999"),
                    TableOperators.And,
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "r11")
                )
            )
            .OrderBy("PartitionKey")
            .Take(10);


        //here, specify ProjectSystemProperties=false, so Rowkey will not be returned since it's not defined in the "IList<string> columns" above.
        foreach (CustomerEntity e in table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery, new TableRequestOptions() { ProjectSystemProperties=false}))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PartitionKey: " +e.PartitionKey + ", RowKey: " + e.RowKey + ", PhoneNumber: " + e.PhoneNumber);
        }
```

The test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`PartitionKey` and `RowKey` are default columns which are always included in the query even if not specified in selected columns.

This can be validated by removing the partition key too from the columns collections even then the result should have `PartitionKey` too.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tablerequestoptions.projectsystemproperties?view=azure-dotnet) if you don't want to include the system properties in the select column by default.